# Will Dragon V2 when crewed carry cargo in its trunk?

Tags: spacex, dragon, dragon-v2

With the reveal of the Dragon V2 (Or is it Dragon 2 now?  Or Dragonrider?) we saw a new trunk design where the solar panels are wrapped around the trunk instead of being deployed like wings from the cargo version of the trunk.

[image: Dragon V2 all around views]

If so, will the new trunk still carry unpressurized cargo to the station?  Or will the available space be used for different purposes?  (Batteries? Abort fuel tanks? Consumables?)

Additionally, if it does, can the CanadArm reach around and into the trunk, when it is docked on the PMA-2 Node-2 forward?  How about PMA-3 Node - 2 Nadir (once it is moved).

Answer (score 3):

So far as I can tell, it seems that SpaceX hasn't fully figured out what will be in the trunk. There is frequent reference to ["Pressurized cargo"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_V2#cite_note-sx20150227-33) that will be contained in the Dragon's pressurized cargo, but nothing said about the trunk.

In fact, it seems as though the use of carrying cargo in the trunk was a bit of an afterthought in the Dragon v1. At the very least, it was not used to carry cargo until [CRS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_CRS-2).

What we do know about the trunk: it contains equipment including "the solar arrays, heat-removal radiators, and will provide aerodynamic stability during emergency aborts".